# Oracle sql with regex - getting duplicate records -

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

here is my table records - table name is temp.

```
1   | java,c,.net
2   | oracle,hadoop,ruby
```

Actually i am looking for data like this.

```
1| java
1 | c
1 | .net
2 | oracle
2| hadoop
2 | ruby
```

I written below query and expected result is not matching. can you please check verify my query why it is causing deplicate,

```
select id,
regexp_substr(liked,'[^,]+', 1, level) from 
temp connect by regexp_substr(liked,'[^,]+', 1, level) is not null order by id
```

Comment: "Result is not matching" is not helpful. Please edit your question and include the results you're getting, along with the results you expected, and the query you used. You've got the last two, but you need to demonstrate *in the question* what the problem is. Providing an SQLFiddle which demonstrates the problem would be a good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
 SELECT id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(liked, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
   FROM temp 
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(liked, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR id = id
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY id;
```

This way using `DISTINCT` is not necessary.

**EDIT:** Without using a random number in the `CONNECT BY` clause, you will get an error as Oracle will think it is an infinite loop.

Comment: NOR it is fully safe. Random may (potentially) return the same result two consecutive times.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "fully safe" - care to explain?

Comment: The `CONNECT BY` may (potentially) appear more than once (low probability, but still > 0).

Comment: why we need PRIOR id = id. if add more column in select clause do i need to add  PRIOR id = id and  PRIOR name = name .. like this

Comment: As long as `id` is the primary key you don't need more columns than that

Comment: It is working fine for my temp table. But in another table doesn't have primary key, i need to consider two columns as primary key. in that case , how can i re-arrage the query

Comment: Use both columns in the `CONNECT BY`: `AND PRIOR x = x AND PRIOR y = y`

Comment: Thanks @David Faber.. Working as expected

Comment: @FDavidov, point taken. Tom Kyte recommends using `SYS_GUID()` which should be non-repeating.

Comment: @DavidFaber, agree with the solution as `SYS_GUID()` is indeed **UNIQUE** in this case.

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact result you're looking for you need to both use DISTINCT and you need to order by LEVEL within ID:

```
SELECT ID, LIKED
  FROM (select DISTINCT id, level, regexp_substr(liked,'[^,]+', 1, level) as liked
          from temp
          connect by regexp_substr(liked,'[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
          order by id, level);
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9630e/45)

Best of luck.

Comment: This is not the way to go. For already several records, it starts to heavily utilize the DB.